# How do I jump to code lines in IntelliJ through code commands

Tags: swing, user-interface, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I'm developing a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA.
Say I'm creating a GUI in my plugin in which I have a button.
On a click I want the editor to jump to a certain file and line in it.
Is it possible? what do I write in the button listener?
My GUI is written with swing if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `OpenFileDescriptor` with the desired file and location inside it, and then call `navigate` on it.